# Close many cursor instances

Tags: android, cursor

I have a food table, where for each row I initiate a cursor instance to get the nutrients for the selected unit of measurement. I wonder how I can close the cursors, since they need to be constantly opened, because the user may at any time choose a different unit of measurement for each food.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

As Quanturium asked the code that initiates the cursor instances is the following method:

```
protected void fillUnitsSpinner(String food) {
    **final Cursor unitsCursor = mDataBaseHelper.getFoodMatches(food, null, 
            CURSOR_FOR_UNITS_SPINNER);**
    final ArrayList<String> foodUnits = new ArrayList<String>();

    foodUnits.clear();
    if(unitsCursor != null) {
        unitsCursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!unitsCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            // Get unit string
            String unit = unitsCursor.getString(unitsCursor.getColumnIndex(FoodDBHelper.UNITS));
            // Get practical units' extra columns if present
            String fingerTip = unitsCursor.getString(unitsCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    FoodDBHelper.FINGERTIP));
            // If practical units are present
            if(fingerTip != null) {
                foodUnits.add(FINGERTIP.getpUnit());
                foodUnits.add(FINGER.getpUnit());
                foodUnits.add(HAND.getpUnit());
                foodUnits.add(FIST.getpUnit());
                foodUnits.add(CUP.getpUnit());
            }
            else foodUnits.add(unit);
            unitsCursor.moveToNext();
        }
        unitsCursor.moveToFirst();
        foodUnitsGlobal = foodUnits;

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> unitsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                R.layout.food_act_units_spinner_dropdown_item);
        unitsAdapter.addAll(foodUnits); // load adapter with food units
        unitsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.food_act_units_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mUnitsSpinner.setAdapter(unitsAdapter); // set adapter
        Log.i(TAG, "spinnerItem = " + unitsAdapter.getItem(foodUnits.indexOf(foodUnits.get(0))));
        // Select and set unit from the main table to the spinner
        if(!editRecord) mUnitsSpinner.setSelection(unitsAdapter.getPosition(foodUnits.get(0)));

        mUnitsSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                Log.i(TAG, "pos = " + pos);
                TextView unitsText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.f_a_units_item);
                View row = (View) parent.getParent();
                row.requestFocus();
                defineViewsInFoodRow(row);

                int pUnitsPos = -1;
                String pShortcutUnit;

                switch(pos) {
                case MAIN_TABLE:
                    unitsCursor.moveToPosition(MAIN_TABLE);
                    break;
                // other cases..
               }
           }
       });
```

Comment: Can you show the code starting the different cursors?

Comment: cursor.close()http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html